# Regular expression for matching the sentences with a specific symbol like %

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want a regular expression for matching the following sentence.

```
myfunc(L"try my number 8 and value%s ",value);
myfunc(L"but %s is not true",word);
myfunc(L"his name is %s ",name);
```

and so on .

but i don't want to match the sentences without % like below

```
myfunc(L"It is raining");
```

ie only the sentence having % should be matched.I tried the following patterns but it matchs sentences without % too.

```
myfunc[(L"(A-Z)*(a-z)*(0-9)*(%)+(a-z)+(A-Z)*(a-z)*(0-9)*(,)+(A-Z)*(a-z)*(0-9))]



myfunc[(%)+]
```

and

```
myfunc[(+(%)+)+]
```

Comment: have you tried `"%" in your_sentence`?

Comment: Any reason you can't use `if '%' in your_str` ?

Comment: i want to handle the whole in Regular expression rather than handling it in code

Comment: @user1654136 do you have examples of sentences those patterns do match but shouldn't? All three of them *should* require at least one % to match. Also, what *exactly* does `myfunc` do? Finally, *why* exactly do you want to use regex here? Using `'%' in sentence` is probably more readable and almost certainly faster than whatever `myfunc` is currently doing.

Comment: i want to use it in the regular expression search for notepad++.That is the reason i can't use "if '%' in your_str".I added python tag beacuse excellent regular expression gurus are always in python :-).Can you please get a regular expression for me.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regular expression for this... or if you really feel you need to use one, all it needs to be, quite literally, is `"%"`.

Why not try the following instead?

```
if '%' in myString:
    ## We have a match!
```

Edit for DSM's comment (and now that you have actually said that this question has nothing to do with Python): From your updates it looks like you actually want to match the whole thing, i.e. "func(...," with the percent sign in the first argument, which is a string. Try the following regex:

```
myfunc\(L\".*?%.*?\",[a-zA-Z]*\)
```

Or, to restrict the other characters in the first parameter string to alphanumerics and spaces, you could try this, which is probably a little more robust than the above:

```
myfunc\(L\"[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*%[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*\",[a-zA-Z]*\)
```

This will ensure that the whole string matches your function prototype shape, including the "L" before the string, the "%" in the string, and the second alphabetical argument before the closing bracket.

Comment: How do you know that the `myfunc(args go here)` wrapping isn't part of the match requirement?  All the examples and the OP's attempted regexes involve it.

Comment: but it is matching only sentence with %d.What is the reason

Comment: @DSM Good point - I have updated my answer to account for that possibility.

Comment: @user1654136 Please see my amended regex following your updates. I have tested this against your inputs using the regex search in Notepad++.